# Qual é a lógica do ForceBrute de tentativa e erro?

Tags: java

Como é feito para fazer as bilhões de combinações possíveis sem perda de tempo?

Fiz um sistema de gera letras aleatórias(ele consegue fazer todas as combinações), porém ele perde muito tempo checando resultados já feitos pelo fato de ser aleatório, e então fiz um sistema com `for` mas só consigo até 2 caracteres.

Isso é o que eu tenho, como eu disse, só consegui com 2 dígitos.

```
public class Main 
{
static boolean terminar = false;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long init  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    if(bruteForce(true, true, "0dd", 10, 10000) != "Senha não encontrada")
    {
        System.out.println("A senha é: " + bruteForce(true, true, "0dd", 10, 10000));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Senha não encontrada"); 
    }

    long end  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    long diff = end - init;
    System.out.println("Demorou " + (diff / 1000) + " segundos");
}
public static String bruteForce(boolean numeros, boolean letras, String busca,int maxCaracteres,  int limite)
{
    String[] todos = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"
                      , "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "k", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
                      , "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"
                      , "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "'", "!", "@", "#", "$", "£", "%", "¢", "¨", "¬", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-"
                      , "+", "=", "§", "/", ".", "[", "]", "`", "´", "{", "}", "º", "^", "~", "<", ">", ":", ";", "?", "°", "ª",
                      "|", "¹", "²", "³"};

    String combinacao = "";
    int quantCaracteres = 2;
    double teste = Math.pow(todos.length, 16);
    System.out.println(teste);  

    for(int i = 1; i <= quantCaracteres; i++)
    {
        for(int h = 0; h <= todos.length -1; h++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <= todos.length -1; j++)
            {
                combinacao = todos[h] + todos[j];
                System.out.println(combinacao); 
                if(combinacao.equals(busca))
                {
                    return combinacao; 
                }

                combinacao = "";
            }
        }

        //quantCaracteres ++;
    }
    return "Senha não encontrada";
}
}
```

Comment: Poste o código que você já tem, podemos te ajudar a corrigí-lo. Quanto à técnica para escolher as combinações, existem várias respostas. O jeito mais simples é iterar a-z, aa-zz (passando por ab, ac, etc.) aaa-zzz... assim por diante.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que você quer? Não deu pra entender direito...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar eu gostaria de uma explicação de qual a melhor forma(que perda menos tempo) de fazer um ataque de força bruta, a melhor maneira de fazer bilhões de combinações.

Comment: @RSinohara Eu editei a pergunta com o código que tenho até agora.

Comment: Eu quis dizer que a forma mais simples é fazer as combinações a, b, c, d, etc, com um caracter, depois aa, ab, ac, ..., fg, fh, ... zz. Depois com 3, etc. Claro que existem meios de evitar combinações inúteis (usar um dicionário), mas a questão é que fazer aleatóriamente é inviável (você começa a repetir sequências).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei este código que pode lhe ajudar. Não vou te garantir que é a melhor forma mas é certamente um bom começo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BruteForce {

  final int min;
  final int max;
  final int stringLength;

  /**
   * One more element than <i>stringLength</i>,
   * to efficiently check for overflow.
   */
  private final int[] chars;

  public BruteForce(char min, char max, int len) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.stringLength = len;

    chars = new int[stringLength + 1];
    Arrays.fill(chars, 1, chars.length, min);
  }

  public void run() {
    while (chars[0] == 0) {
      print();
      increment();
    }
  }

  private void increment() {
    for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (chars[i] < max) {
        chars[i]++;
        return;
      }
      chars[i] = min;
    }
  }

  private void print() {
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
      System.out.print((char) chars[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BruteForce('a', 'z', 4).run();
  }

}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/BruteForce.java).

[Fonte](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10356).

Tem formas mais simples que esta. É possível fazer com apenas dois `for` aninhados, uma para ir incrementando a posição do caractere e o outro para ir incrementando o caractere em si. Mas dá até para fazer com apenas um laço se usar a criatividade.

Existem técnicas mais avançadas de força bruta mas elas jogam com probabilidades. Para algo simples o fato é que você precisa manter a sequência. O que você não pode é ir chutando valores aleatórios, isso provavelmente dará resultados bem piores na maioria das tentativas.

Answer (score 0):

Então,pelo o que vc disse, seu código testa várias vezes a mesma combinação. Uma forma de diminuir, é guardar as combinações e verificar se já foi testada. 
Vc também pode utilizar um dicionário de combinações...
Segue um link q pode lhe ajudar: 
http://pt.slideshare.net/clavissecurity/webinar-16-ataques-de-fora-bruta-mtodo-dicionrio-hbridos-e-rainbow-tables